# Determining the required angular velocity to reach a target, given a starting angle

Tags: circles, angle

I expected this issue to be much easier to solve than it turned out to be.

A vehicle starts at point A and moves through point B in geometric space. It travels at a constant speed v, and starts out with angle $\theta$ (where 0 degrees is northward). The vehicle needs to have a certain angle change per second to reach point B given these parameters.

I've been having trouble determining the length of the traveled arc. Is there an exact method to determine the required angular velocity?

Comment: Do you want the angular velocity or the length of the arc?

Comment: Not very clear does it move in a circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vehicle’s velocity is always tangent to its path, which in this case is a circular arc. A tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the circle’s radius at the point of tangency, which means that the angle of arc subtended by the vehicle’s path from $A$ to $B$ is equal to its net change in heading. By symmetry, the angle between the ray from $A$ through $B$ and the vehicle’s final heading is equal and opposite to the angle made by its initial heading. Call the latter angle $\phi$, so that the total change in heading from $A$ to $B$ is $2\phi$. If you can compute the bearing from $A$ to $B$ directly, then you just need to subtract $\theta$ from this bearing to get $\phi$, otherwise you can compute it from the dot product or cross product of the initial velocity vector with $\overrightarrow{AB}$.

Now, for a circle of radius $R$, the arc length corresponding to a central angle of $2\phi$ is $2R\phi$, while the corresponding chord length is $2R\sin\phi$, which makes the ratio of chord length to arc length ${\sin\phi\over\phi}$. Assuming that $A$ and $B$ are distinct so that $\sin\phi\ne0$, the distance traveled by the vehicle is ${\phi\over\sin\phi}AB$, from which we can compute $\omega = {2v\over AB}\sin\phi$. Note that this formula preserves the sign of $\phi$: In other words, it can tell the difference between a left and right turn to reach $B$.

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\theta$ be the launch angle (from vertical). You need angular velocity I.e. $\omega=\dfrac{v}{r}$.

You already have $v$. Now, we only need to determine $r$, the radius of the circle, whose arc is $AB$.

Let the center of the circle be $O$. We have $OA=OB=r$ (let $AB=d$ )and  $\angle BAO=\angle ABO=\theta$.

Using all this given data, and applying cosine formula, you get $$\cos\theta = \frac{d^2+r^2-r^2}{2dr}\implies d=2r\cos\theta$$ or :$$r=\frac{d}{2}\sec \theta$$

Hence $$\omega =\frac vr= \frac{2v}{AB}\cos \theta$$

Comment: You appear to have conflated two different angles here. How do you justify $\angle{BAO}=\theta$? Consider, for example, $A=(-1,1)$, $B=(1,-1)$ and $\theta=45°$ (assuming positive angles are clockwise, which is common when “North” is $0°$). $O$ is obviously the origin, and $\angle{BAO}$ is most certainly not equal to $\theta$.

Comment: Unfortunately, your formula only works when  θ = 90°.